# Count function is only returning one row, but showing the count of the top 5 flightnumbers for only one customer. What is the problem here?

Tags: mysql

The problem is we are trying to show the top 5 customers in terms of flightnum, so instead of getting the top 5, we get the count of flightnum of the top 5, but only one row(passengerid, passfname, passlname)

```
Select distinct p.PassengerID, p.PassFName, p.PassLName, Count(distinct 
f.FlightNum)
from Passenger p, Flight f, PassengerFlight x
where p.passengerID = x.passengerid
and f.flightnum = x.flightnum
Order by f.flightnum DESC
limit 5
;
```

Max Flights
Show the top 5 passengers, in terms of the total number of flights taken.

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` is kinda wonky sometimes in MySQL. You would probably be better off using a `GROUP BY` and only use `DISTINCT` for the `COUNT`, like this:

```
      SELECT p.PassengerID, 
             p.PassFName, 
             p.PassLName, 
             COUNT(DISTINCT f.FlightNum) AS numFlights
        FROM Passenger p, Flight f, PassengerFlight x
       WHERE p.passengerID = x.passengerid
         AND f.flightnum = x.flightnum
    GROUP BY p.PassengerID, p.PassFName, p.PassLName
    ORDER BY numFlights DESC
       LIMIT 5;
```